# friendly_id creates new entry on UPDATE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I'm using friendly_id 5.1.0, and when I try to update an entry, for exemple creating a new Article, instead of updating the data of the entry, it creates a new one.
I have slugged the title and when I don't change it when editing an article, it creates a slug with a bunch of numbers/letters :

```
http://localhost:3000/articles/first-article-2d392b8e-92b8-44b0-ad67-50dd674f7aaa
```

Here's my article.rb Model :

```Ruby
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend FriendlyId
    has_many :comments

    friendly_id :title, :use => :slugged

    validates :title,   presence: true,
                        length: { minimum: 5}


    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
         new_record? || title_changed?
    end
```

when I add `:use => [:slugged, :history]`, when I update an entry and keep the same title, it can't save it because my `:slug` field is `unique :true`. 
Here's my articles_controller.rb :

```Ruby
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @articles = Article.all.order(created_at: :desc)
    end 

    def show
        @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:id])
        if request.path != article_path(@article)
            redirect_to @article, status: :moved_permanently
        end
    end

    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def edit
        @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        if @article.save
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end 

    def update
        @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:id])

        if @article.update(article_params)
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:id])
        @article.destroy

        redirect_to articles_path
    end

    private
        def article_params
            params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)  
    end
end
```

Here's my GitHub repository whith my (unfinished) project : https://github.com/TheDoctor314/blog

Comment: Just try using title_changed? in your should_generate_new_friendly_id method

Comment: Doesn't work :'( . Even stranger : without 'new_record?' it still gererates a slug when creating a new article

Comment: It will always create a slug on new_record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This issue has nothing to do with FriendlyID.**

Your problem is **[here](https://github.com/TheDoctor314/blog/blob/master/app/views/articles/_form.html.erb#L2)** (a form used on both `new` and `edit`):

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
```

It does not attempt to use your `@article` object to built that form. So your form always issues a `POST` request to `articles_path`, which results in `create` every time. What you should do instead is:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @article do |f| %>
```

That way form builder will check if that object is `persisted?` already, and if so, generate a form that issues a `PATCH` request to that specific article that triggers an `update` action. It will try to guess the URL by itself. And it will succeeed only if you follow conventions tightly enough.

If `@article` is not `persisted?`, it will do what it did: make a `POST` to `articles_path`.

Answer (score 0):

Permit `id` in params

```
params.require(:article).permit(:id, :title, :text)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nope :( still creates a new entry. Maybe I could tell rails to delete the previous entry , by forcing a DELETE request ?

Comment: This is a common pitfall when using nested forms, yes. Forget an `id` and `accepts_nested_attributes` treats parameter as a new entry. But it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

The Edit form is routing to create action for articles controller instead of update action. You need to change your form path, when editing the files.

If you see the articles index action, you can see new articles are being added, instead of updating